# dense_rank max OVER 3 days?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, greatest-n-per-group, date

How do I get the MAX (or another aggregate function) for of a column of each row, OVER its 3 days worth of rows?

SQL example with expected output and db schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/24686/3

```
CREATE TABLE public.tbl (
  date    DATE       NOT NULL,
  someNum DECIMAL    NOT NULL,
  name    VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  elem    VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("date", someNum, "name", elem)
);

INSERT INTO public.tbl ("date", someNum, "name", elem) VALUES
  ('2017-12-05', 50.5, '0hello', 'nice elem'),
  ('2017-12-05', 05.5, '1hello', 'nice elem'),
  ('2017-12-05', 55.5, '2hello', 'nice elem'),
  ('2017-12-09', 59.5, '3hello', 'nice elem'),
  ('2017-12-09', 60.5, '4hello', 'nice elem'),
  ('2017-12-10', 90.5, '5hello', 'nice elem'),
  ('2017-12-12', 10.5, '6hello', 'nice elem'),
  ('2017-12-15', 50.3, '7hello', 'nice elem'),
  ('2017-12-30', 70.5, '8hello', 'nice elem'),
  ('2018-01-01', 50.5, '9hello', 'nice elem'),
  ('2017-12-05', 05.5, '10ello', 'mean elem'),
  ('2017-12-05', 5505, '11ello', 'mean elem'),
  ('2017-12-05', 6045, '12ello', 'mean elem'),
  ('2017-12-03', 9045, '13ello', 'mean elem'),
  ('2017-12-04', 1345, '14ello', 'mean elem'),
  ('2017-10-02', 1111, '15ello', 'mean elem'),
  ('2017-10-03', 5555, '16ello', 'mean elem'),
  ('2017-10-04', 66.6, '16ello', 'mean elem');
```

Desired output,

```
-- MAX over 3 day period
-- date         somenum     name        elem            max_over_3days
-- 2017-10-02   1111        '15ello'    'mean elem'     5555
-- 2017-10-03   5555        '16ello'    'mean elem'     5555
-- 2017-10-04   66.6        '16ello'    'mean elem'     5555
-- 2017-12-03   9045        '13ello'    'mean elem'     9045
-- 2017-12-05   6045        '12ello'    'mean elem'     9045
-- 2017-12-04   1345        '14ello'    'mean elem'     9045
-- 2017-12-05   05.5        '10ello'    'mean elem'     9045
-- 2017-12-05   5505        '11ello'    'mean elem'     9045
-- 2017-12-05   50.5        '0hello'    'nice elem'     9045
-- 2017-12-05   55.5        '2hello'    'nice elem'     9045
-- 2017-12-05   05.5        '1hello'    'nice elem'     9045
-- 2017-12-09   60.5        '4hello'    'nice elem'     90.5
-- 2017-12-09   59.5        '3hello'    'nice elem'     90.5
-- 2017-12-10   90.5        '5hello'    'nice elem'     99.5
-- 2017-12-13   99.5        '6hello'    'nice elem'     99.5
-- 2017-12-15   50.3        '7hello'    'nice elem'     99.5
-- 2017-12-30   70.5        '8hello'    'nice elem'     70.5
-- 2018-01-01   50.5        '9hello'    'nice elem'     70.5

SELECT * FROM public.tbl
GROUP BY elem, "date", name, someNum
ORDER BY elem, "date";
```

PS: Also interested with how I can cover 3 work days rather than calendar days

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/24686/3 , the `max_over_3days` of `2017-12-04` should be `6045`, right ?

Comment: No, `9045`, because `2017-12-03` has `9045`, so the `MAX` would be that. Also interested in other aggregate functions, `MAX` to illustrate the case.

Comment: What he really wants is RANGE with a defined window. PostgreSQL doesn't have that yet.

Answer (score 1):

## Using `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`

The output is similar to your [output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/24686/3), but please check again. Here's, I using [lateral](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) (as loop) to find the max value of `someNume` for the 3 surrounding days (*it doesn't mention about performance*).

```
SELECT tbl.date, tbl.somenum, tbl.name, tbl.elem, t2.max_somenum
FROM tbl
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT MAX(t2.somenum) AS max_somenum
  FROM tbl t2 
  WHERE t2.date >= (tbl.date - interval '3 days') AND t2.date <= (tbl.date + interval '3 days')
) t2
ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: Great answer, this is how I would do it too. Stick around! Except I would make sure t2.date and tbl.date was always `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` before you did the date math so you don't throw different results on DST

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/24686/15

Note: It wasn't clear what 3 surrounding days meant, so I just divided the date range into groups of 3 days based on dense rank.  If you wanted 3 days (prior date, this date, next date) you could use LEAD / LAG or, if your database supported it, see "window frame between" in the spec.  That should do it.

For my example: I include a few extra calculations for you to consider.

Basically, we obtain the dense rank of each row by date and then divide by 3 (with integer truncation) to calculate a value which allows grouping the rows in groups of 3 (dates) via the PARTITION BY clause.  The MAX window function is then applied to these partitions.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
          SELECT t.*
               , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date, someNum, "name") AS rn
               , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date                 ) AS rn2
               , RANK()       OVER (ORDER BY date, someNum, "name") AS r
               , RANK()       OVER (ORDER BY date                 ) AS r2
               , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY date                 ) AS r3
            FROM public.tbl AS t
     )
   , cte2 AS (
          SELECT c1.*
               , r3/3                 AS part
               , ((r3-1)/3)           AS part2
            FROM cte1 AS c1
     )
SELECT c2.*
     , SUM(someNum) OVER (PARTITION BY part2) AS sumv
     , MIN(someNum) OVER (PARTITION BY part2) AS minv
     , MAX(someNum) OVER (PARTITION BY part2) AS maxv
  FROM cte2 AS c2
 ORDER BY elem, date
;
```

After further review, it looks like your expected results are wrong, if you wanted the max for 3 days (1 before, current, 1 after).  Here's the solution for that case:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/24686/26

```
WITH cte1 AS (
          SELECT t.date
               , MAX(t.someNum) AS maxnum
            FROM public.tbl AS t
           GROUP BY t.date
     )
   , cte2 AS (
          SELECT c1.date
               , c1.maxnum
               , MAX(maxnum) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS maxnum2
            FROM cte1 AS c1
     )
SELECT t.*
     , c2.maxnum2
  FROM public.tbl AS t
  JOIN cte2       AS c2
    ON c2.date = t.date
 ORDER BY t.elem, t.date
;
```

**Additionally, if your database supports it, see: "MAX(someNum) OVER (ORDER BY date RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING)"**

Comment: Btw, you also have data in your expected results that are not in your test data.  You can't have a MAX that isn't in the set (see: 99.5).